# How to batch requests to the same URL without causing memory leaks

Tags: axios, nestjs

I have a system that processes images.  Essentially, I provide an ID to it, and it fetches a source image, and then it begins performing transformations on it to resize and reformat it.

This system gets quite a bit of usage, and one of the things that I've noticed is that I tend to get many requests for the same ID simultaneously, but in different requests to the webserver.

What I'd like to do is "batch" these requests.  For example, if there's 5 simultaneous requests for the image "user-upload.png", I'd like there to be only one HTTP request to fetch the source image.

I'm using NestJS with default scopes for my service, so the service is shared between requests.  Requests to fetch the image are done with the HttpModule, which is using axios internally.

I only care about simultaneous requests.  Once the request finishes, it will be cached, and that prevents new requests from hitting the HTTP url.

I've thought about doing something like this (Pseudocode):

```
@Provider()
class ImageFetcher {
  // Store in flight requests as a map between id:promise
  inFlightRequests = { }

  fetchImage(id: string) {
    if (this.inFlightRequests[id]) {
      return this.inFlightRequests[id]
    }

    this.inFlightRequests[id] = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const { data } = await this.httpService.get('/images' + id)

      // error handling omitted here
      resolve(data)
      delete inFlightRequests[id]
    })

    return this.inFlightRequests[id]
  }
}
```

The most obvious issue I see is the potential for a memory leak.  This is solveable with more custom code, but I thought I'd see if anyone has any suggestions for doing this without writing more code.

In particular, I've also thought about using an axios interceptor, but I'm not entirely sure how to handle that properly.  Any pointers here would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply manage the promise cache in `this.httpService` (since its `get` mothod returns a promise anyway)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I should clarify that this code is more of an example of what I'm trying to do.  I'm not as concerned with what the promise is; I'm much more concerned with how to cache that promise without creating a memory leak or write a whole bunch of state management code.  What you suggest is still susceptible to a memory leak if anybody forgets to `delete` the record in the map.

Comment: There's no leak here: the only way it wouldn't be deleted is if the async promise callback threw an exception before reaching the delete statement. Just wrap everything in `try/catch/finally` and put the delete statement in the `finally` block, and no matter what happens, the cache entry will be deleted.